# Reference Request for calculus self study

Tags: calculus, reference-request

I'm wishing to learn calculus in a detailed manner. 
could any one help me by giving  suggestions?

I'm looking for books with good illustrative examples and figures.

Comment: As we all know, the only calculus book worthy of the name is: [Spivak Calculus](http://www.amazon.com/Calculus-4th-Michael-Spivak/dp/0914098918).

Comment: I believe the most used book is Calculus: Early Transcendentals by Stewart. Spivak is another good book as said by Hakim.

Comment: There are many good calculus books. The problem about recommendations is that different books suit different people. A gold medal winner at the IMO, or the top guy in the Putnam, is likely to prefer different books to someone who has little interest in the subject, but needs a certificate to show he once passed an exam in calculus.

Comment: What about Tom Apostol's books? Is it easy to understand?

Comment: If you really want a book for self study then go for Hardy's Pure Mathematics. Next best option is Spivak Calculus. One should note however that Spivak book is huge in size compared to Hardy's and contains almost the same material as Hardy's book.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The advantage of Spivak's book over Hardy's is that the former introduces much more material in his exercises.

Comment: @Hakim: The number of exercises in Hardy's book is not less (there ia enough variety and lot of tough problems). What Spivak does to increase the size of the book is to add lot of figures which is helpful. Spivak seems more suited to the the current syllabus in most universities where Hardy's book has a very different (but more natural) presentation and therefore I said it is good for self-study. If you are attending a school then it is better to go for Spivak.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I'm not talking about the number of exercises but about the number of external material that is introduced in those exercises. For example Spivak introduces the countability of the rationals and many other topics in his exercises which is a major advantage.

Comment: @Hakim: don't you think that construction of regular polygons is far more interesting than countability of rationals. hardy discusses way too interesting topics in his exercises. another is addition formula for elliptic integrals. then the point about integration in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Not false, perhaps a better choice would be to use both texts. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[This GATech site](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~cain/textbooks/onlinebooks.html) contains a list of free math textbooks as pdfs.  There are several calculus textbooks that may be useful to you, including a multivariable textbook, one for Calc I and II, another standard calculus book, and what I believe is an introduction to calculus using nonstandard analysis!

Answer (score 1):

I heartily recommend Marsden and Weinstein's Calculus I, Calculus II, and Calculus III. They are excellent and have many examples and figures but are not so widely used today.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend Marsden and Weinsten. I was working with several books including Spivak and Thomas' Calculus. Marsden and Weinstein were the most efficient.

Comment: It strikes me as odd that your only three posts are recommendations for this book. Should I find this odd?

Comment: actually if you find it odd, your intuition is correct. I did register here because I was thankful that I found this awesome material, so I felt like I wanna give something back. The pdf can be downloaded for free, and the autor has even answered my email. I find this unbelievable. So much kindness has to be rewarded. Thus I registered and wrote a recommendation, thats all I can do.

Comment: Fair enough! It just caught my attention, that's all :)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend ["A Problem Text in Advanced Calculus".](http://web.pdx.edu/~erdman/PTAC/problemtext_pdf.pdf) The approach taken in this book is quite unique.